# Angularjs PHP $http and populating $scope in a controller with data

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

Ok here we go. I have an angularjs platform and I want to call the data in my controllers scope from an external php files. This is the original code.

```
.controller("morrisChartCtrl", ["$scope",
        function ($scope) {
            return $scope.mainData = [{
                month: "2013-01",
                xbox: 294e3,
                will: 136e3,
                playstation: 244e3
            }, {
                month: "2013-02",
                xbox: 228e3,
                will: 335e3,
                playstation: 127e3
            }, {
                month: "2013-03",
                xbox: 199e3,
                will: 159e3,
                playstation: 13e4
            }, {
                month: "2013-04",
                xbox: 174e3,
                will: 16e4,
                playstation: 82e3
            }, {
                month: "2013-05",
                xbox: 255e3,
                will: 318e3,
                playstation: 82e3
            }, {
                month: "2013-06",
                xbox: 298400,
                will: 401800,
                playstation: 98600
            }, {
                month: "2013-07",
                xbox: 37e4,
                will: 225e3,
                playstation: 159e3
            }, {
                month: "2013-08",
                xbox: 376700,
                will: 303600,
                playstation: 13e4
            }, {
                month: "2013-09",
                xbox: 527800,
                will: 301e3,
                playstation: 119400
            }], $scope.simpleData = [{
                year: "2008",
                value: 20
            }, {
                year: "2009",
                value: 10
            }, {
                year: "2010",
                value: 5
            }, {
                year: "2011",
                value: 5
            }, {
                year: "2012",
                value: 20
            }, {
                year: "2013",
                value: 19
            }], $scope.comboData = [{
                year: "2008",
                a: 20,
                b: 16,
                c: 12
            }, {
                year: "2009",
                a: 10,
                b: 22,
                c: 30
            }, {
                year: "2010",
                a: 5,
                b: 14,
                c: 20
            }, {
                year: "2011",
                a: 5,
                b: 12,
                c: 19
            }, {
                year: "2012",
                a: 20,
                b: 19,
                c: 13
            }, {
                year: "2013",
                a: 28,
                b: 22,
                c: 20
            }], $scope.donutData = [{
                label: "Download Sales",
                value: 12
            }, {
                label: "In-Store Sales",
                value: 30
            }, {
                label: "Mail-Order Sales",
                value: 20
            }, {
                label: "Online Sales",
                value: 19
            }]
        }
    ])
```

Instead of inline data in the js file I want to use `$http` to get the code for each scope from a individual php file that will generate to JSON format.

What is wrong with this format

```
.controller("morrisChartCtrl", ["$scope",
        function ($scope) {
            return $scope.mainData = $http.get('php/mainData.php').success(function (data) {
    $scope.mainData = data;
}), $scope.simpleData = $http.get('php/simpleData.php').success(function (data) {
    $scope.simpleData = data;
}), $scope.comboData = $http.get('php/comboData.php').success(function (data) {
    $scope.comboData = data;
}), $scope.donutData = $http.get('php/donutData.php').success(function (data) {
    $scope.donutData = data;
})
        }
    ])
```

Just trying to figure out the right structure

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/ajax.html

Comment: what is the question? You already know about `$http`, read the docs , go through the docs tutorial code that shows examples...do some research in other words.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is if I have the inline code there what would be the structure of creating $http driven version something like the following

Answer (score 1):

What you get as a result of `$http.get()` is a promise object. Avoid assigning the result of `$http.get()` to a scope variable.

```
.controller("morrisChartCtrl", ["$scope",
  function ($scope) {
    var mainDataPromise = $http.get('php/mainData.php');
    mainDataPromise.success(function (data) {
      $scope.mainData = data;
    }); 

    var simpleDataPromise = $http.get('php/simpleData.php');
    simpleDataPromise.success(function (data) {
      $scope.simpleData = data;
    });

    var comboDataPromise = $http.get('php/comboData.php');
    comboDataPromise.success(function (data) {
      $scope.comboData = data;
    })

    var donutDataPromise = $http.get('php/donutData.php');
    donutDataPromise.success(function (data) {
      $scope.donutData = data;
    });
  }
])
```

Comment: When I replace the code I loose all data either it is not returning the data or the data is not formatted correctly and I am trying to figure that out. i literally took the data displayed and put it into a php file and used echo ' the data '; not sure if that is correct or even if the file path is the issue